# Svg path orthogonal or perpendicular line create correct way

Tags: html, svg

I'm going to create diagram.

I want this type of line.
[image]

but im confusing svg path data. im already try lot of ways.

my code.

```
<svg>
      <path
        d="
    M 80,10
    l 10,0
    v -10,0
    h 10,0
    "
        fill="none"
        stroke="#558822"
        stroke-width="2"
      ></path>
    </svg>
```

result.

[image]

Comment: why is the result not what you want? It looks basically similar to the bottom left connector.

Comment: This is actual problem

Comment: sorry, sir my mistake please see my edited question.

Comment: Again, what exactly is the problem here? Have you read [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataLinetoCommands)